# How to add new coupon Type such as 'No Coupon', 'Specfic Coupon' in Magento2.1?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise

How to add new coupon Type such as 'No Coupon', 'Specfic Coupon' in Magento2.1 ?

Comment: Go to `Admin -> Marketing -> Cart Price Rules` http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart.html

Comment: Ankit Shah-  Thanks for the update. But my question was different. I want new option e.g. Project Auto in the drop down of Coupons.